# Local variable referenced before assignment; Static Class attribute for number of players

Tags: python, class, variables, pygame, global

I want to hold a static class attribute number_of_players, which tells the game how many players have decided to play, that can be modified throughout my classes.

I have my parent class:

```
class SceneBase:
    number_of_players = None
#more code
```

However, in the child class, when I try to modify the number_of_players, i'm getting the local variable is referenced before assingment error.

```
class ChooseNumberOfPlayersScene(SceneBase):

    def change_to_one_player_mode(self):

        number_of_players = 1
        print("The number of players is now" + number_of_players)
```

I have also tried initializing the number of players as a self attribute

```
class SceneBase:

    def __init__(self):

        self.number_of_players = None
```

But when I try running that with this:

```
class ChooseNumberOfPlayersScene(SceneBase):

        def change_to_one_player_mode(self):

            self.number_of_players = 1
            print("The number of players is now" + self.number_of_players)
```

self.number_of_players never changes and returns None

I'm confused as to how to modify my number of players. Is there a way I can make it modifiable by all classes?

Comment: `SceneBase.number_of_players` if you do a class member attribute then you have to access it like one

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an instance variable for this.  Just set `self.number_of_players` to override the default value for a specific class instance.

Comment: @user1767754 I don't think the intent was to modify the base class.

Comment: He is not modifying the base class, he want's a `Class` that act's like a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass the number of players to the next scene directly or let the scene manager transfer it to the next scene (maybe in a `persistent_data` dictionary that is passed to all scenes).

```
class ChooseNumberOfPlayersScene:

    def __init__(self):
        self.next_scene = None
        self.number_of_players = 1

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_n:
                # Create the next scene instance and pass
                # the number_of_players to the game scene.
                self.next_scene = GameScene(self.number_of_players)
            elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                self.number_of_players += 1

class GameScene:

    def __init__(self, number_of_players):
        self.number_of_players = number_of_players
```

The `SceneManager` switches the scene `if scene.next_scene is not None`.

Alternatively, I think it would be okay to just use a global variable here if it's only modified in the `ChooseNumberOfPlayersScene`.

Comment: BTW, please upvote and accept helpful questions by clicking on the checkmark (that gives you 2 reputation points as well).

Comment: One note about global variables: You usually shouldn't use them, because they can make code more difficult to understand, debug and maintain. In this case since it's only modified by one function/method you could use one, however, personally I'd choose one of the first two options. Be careful and absolutely don't use globals for every problem.